# Pandas - Combine rows with similar values (name spelling variations)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have the following Python Pandas Dataframe:

```
   Name        Sales Qty
0 JOHN BARNES   10
1 John Barnes    5
2 John barnes    4
3 Peter K.       4
4 Peter K        6
5 Peter Krammer  5
6 Charles        3
7 CHARLES        2
8 Julie Moore    3
9 Julie moore    7
10

And many more, with same name spelling variations.
```

I would like to combine the rows with similar values, such that I have the following Dataframe:

```
  Name           Sales Qty
0 John Barness   19
1 Peter Krammer  15
2 Charles         5
3 Julie Moore    10

and many more
```

How should I do?

Comment: What if Peter K and Peter Krammer are two different people? What if you Peter's full name is Peter MiddleName Kramer and only some entries have the the middle name or initial? There are a lot of hidden requirements here, this question isn't well defined (a good start would be to define what "similarity" between names means).

Comment: df.groupby("Name").sum() I think can work here. Cause I don't know what defines similarity rn.

Comment: In this example, Peter K and Peter Krammer and Peter K. are one same people. That is why the sum all the sales qty is 15. The different is only in name spelling. John Barnes with other two spelling variations are also the same people. Charles and Julie Moore are the same case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements are vague, as you can see in the comments, but I've tabulated the totals as far as I can tell. I tallied the total by lowercasing the name and removing the period, and converted it to uppercase with `str.title()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''
 Name Sales
0 "JOHN BARNES" 10
1 "John Barnes" 5
2 "John barnes" 4
3 "Peter K." 4
4 "Peter K" 6
5 "Peter Krammer" 5
6 "Charles"  3
7 "CHARLES"  2
8 "Julie Moore" 3
9 "Julie moore" 7
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
df['lower'] = df['Name'].str.lower()
df['lower'] = df['lower'].str.replace('.','')
new = df.groupby('lower')['Sales'].sum().reset_index()
new['lower'] = new['lower'].str.title()

new
    lower   Sales
0   Charles 5
1   John Barnes 19
2   Julie Moore 10
3   Peter K 10
4   Peter Krammer   5
```

Comment: Thanks! Not fully answer my question, but I think is OK.